# multi-index notatons

Tags: notation, index-notation

I have two index $p_i^j$ where $i=1,2,\dots n$ and $j=1,2,\dots,\infty$, i.e the elements are $p_1^1,p_2^1,\dots,p_n^1$, $p_1^2,p_2^2,\dots,p_n^2$, $\dots$, could anyone tell me how to write them in a compact form? $\{p_i^j\}_{i=1}^{n}$ is not working. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Perhaps $\{p_{i}^j\}_{i,j =1}^n$? But if this isn't what you're looking for, then you should explain what exactly you're trying to do, and what you mean by "is not working".

Comment: I mean, $p_i^j$ is compact. Do you mean how to write the *set* of them? In that case you could just say $\{p_i^j\}$ and explain how the indices range using words. Or use two lines over top each other in set builder notation but that's hard with LaTeX...

Comment: yes I want to write in set notation....

Comment: how come $\{p_i^j\}_{i,j=1}^n$ works? $j=1,\to \infty$

Comment: $\{\{p_i^j\}_{i=1}^n\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ works????????????